# Is it possible to have another object type as a property of SQL Server entity without using relation

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have smaller separate models I don't want to map to SQL Server database table. Is it possible to use them as properties of an object that's mapped to SQL Server table?

I know SQL Server is relational, but of a case where I don't to map these separate models to database table? I have done it several times with non relational databases like MongoDb.

Here is and example what I want to achieve

The `DbContext` class:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext: DbContext
{
    ....
    public DbSet<User> Users {get; set;}
}
```

`User` class:

```
public class User 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public LoginProfile LoginProfile { get; set; }
}
```

`LoginProfile` class:

```
public class LoginProfile
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

In the above example `User` model class is the only one I want to have as table in my database. Is it possible to do that, and do things like

```
var password = user.LoginProfile.Password;
user.LoginProfile.username = "username";
```

Comment: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/included-properties

Comment: Depending on EF (6 or Core), you are looking for Complex Types or Owned Entity Types.